# Repopulating selectlist for dropdownlist on postback when default selected ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, postback, viewmodel

New to ASP.NET MVC and I've come across this before, however I feel I've gone about fixing it in an incorrect way.  I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of the correct way of doing it.

I have a page which the user selects a dropdown value and clicks next.  Now, if they don't select an item and select the default value ("Select..."), there is a validation error.  The controller seems to lose information about the dropdownlist even though the model is returned to the view on a "postback."  So, say I don't basically repeat code in my `[HTTPPost]` from my `[HTTPGet]`.  I get the error:

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SheetIndex'.
```

on

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SheetIndex, Model.SheetsDropdown, "Select...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

So unless I repeat code,  I get that error when no selection is made.  What am I doing wrong?

ViewModel:

```
public class SelectSheetViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SheetIndex { get; set; }
    public string SheetName { get; set; }
    public int? ChainId { get; set; }
    public int? SheetId { get; set; }
    public int? FileId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SheetsDropdown { get; set; }
    public HeaderViewModel Header { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SelectSheet(int? chainId, int? sheetId, int? fileId)
{
    if (sheetId == null || fileId == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var fileDetails = db.FileDetails.Find(fileId);

    SelectSheetViewModel selectSheet = new SelectSheetViewModel()
    {
        Id = fileDetails.FileId,
        Name = fileDetails.Name,
        ChainId = chainId,
        SheetId = sheetId,
        FileId = fileId
    };

    string fileName = fileDetails.UniqueName + fileDetails.Extension;
    string relativeFileLocation = "~/uploads/" + fileName;
    string absoluteFileLocation = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(relativeFileLocation);         

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(absoluteFileLocation))
    {
        DSDBuilder builder = new DSDBuilder();

        selectSheet.SheetsDropdown = builder.GetSheets(absoluteFileLocation); // Where I get my selectlist
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("SheetDropdown", "Excel workbook does not exist.");
    }

    selectSheet.Header = BuildHeaderViewModel(chainId, sheetId);

    return View(selectSheet);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectSheet(SelectSheetViewModel selectSheet)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        FileDetail fileDetails = db.FileDetails.Find(selectSheet.FileId);

        string[] sheetIndexAndName = selectSheet.SheetIndex.Split(':');

        fileDetails.SheetIndex = Convert.ToInt32(sheetIndexAndName[0]);
        fileDetails.SheetName = sheetIndexAndName[1];

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Build", "Sheets", new
        {
            ChainId = selectSheet.ChainId,
            SheetId = selectSheet.SheetId,
            FileId = selectSheet.FileId
        });
    }


    // Probably not a good method vvv
    var fileDetailsPostBack = db.FileDetails.Find(selectSheet.FileId);

    string fileName = fileDetailsPostBack.UniqueName + fileDetailsPostBack.Extension;
    string relativeFileLocation = "~/uploads/" + fileName;
    string absoluteFileLocation = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(relativeFileLocation);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(absoluteFileLocation))
    {
        DSDBuilder builder = new DSDBuilder();

        selectSheet.SheetsDropdown = builder.GetSheets(absoluteFileLocation);
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("SheetDropdown", "Excel workbook does not exist.");
    }
    // Probably not a good method ^^^

    return View(selectSheet);
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChainId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SheetId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FileId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Header.ChainName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Header.SheetName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Header.SheetDescription)
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SheetIndex, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SheetIndex, Model.SheetsDropdown, "Select...", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SheetIndex, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Next" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I also would not like to repeat that code because it goes to a function which uses Excel.Interop and is kind of resource heavy. Let me know if anyone has a better solution. I'm always trying to improve my code and do things the "correct" way.

Comment: I know you said you don't want to repeat code, but have you tried repeating your code?  I mean, I don't know of a way for the program to know what is supposed to be in the DropDownList without some initialization/assigning... since you are essentially 'redirecting' due to validation errors.. the view doesn't go back to the `HttpGet` action, it instead just returns what it knows from the `HttpPost`.  And in your case, the view doesn't know anything about `SheetIndex` or `SheetsDropdown` because it is nowhere to be found in your `HttpPost` Action.

Comment: I am repeating my code in the Post between the comments ``// Probably not a good method``.  It works with that section of code there but it just feels wrong... there must be a way to retrieve it from the model and put it back.  Maybe I'm just wrong here?

Comment: ahh I didn't see that comment.. but I have done some research of the problem you are experiencing, and all of the solutions I have found result in declaring the value in both the `HttpGet` and `HttpPost`, and in my personal experience I do the same.. I apologize I couldn't think of another solution, but honestly I haven't seen one

Comment: I mean what if you did what you are trying in the constuctor of your model/class?

Comment: I would have to pass it the FileId because it has to go and check an uploaded Excel file for the sheet names to populate the SelectListItems, so I can't really do it with the constructor. I just want to do that as little as possible because of the having to use Excel.Interop and re-running the Excel process on the server to do the same thing again.  I wish I could save it off somehow and reuse it.  I could use a temp table, but I feel that's not a good solution, either.

Comment: Is it concerning you because it is running slow?  Will repeating the code, decrease the scalability?

Comment: You need to repopulate the `SelectList` because you do not (and should not) generate form controls for each property of each `SelectListItem` in the view. If you have correctly implemented client side validation, then validation errors will be shown in the client the form will not be submitted anyway (it would only be a malicious user that might cause `ModelState` to be invalid in the server. You can always consider caching the `SelectList` (e.g. `MemoryCache` or `Session`)